# How can I create a custom Player class? (Bukkit)

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

This is mainly for the Spigot API, but I want to be able to take the "Player" Object and cast it to a custom object in order to add new methods and I want to be able to do something like:

```
User user = (User) Bukkit.getPlayer("player_name");
```

I know this may not be answered but it would be extremely helpful to learn how to do this

EDIT: I need to know how I would accomplish the User class/interface

Answer (score 2):

You can't cast an object to `SomeClass` unless the object is actually an instance of `SomeClass` or its subclass. I assume extending the player class is not an option since you can't change what `Bukkit.getPlayer()` returns. What you can do is wrap the player object in your custom `User` class like this:

```
class User {

    private Player player;

    public User(Player player) {
        this.player = player;
    }

    // your custom methods
}
```

Change `Player` to the appropriate type returned by `Bukkit.getPlayer()`. Then you can use you class:

```
User user = new User(Bukkit.getPlayer("player_name"));
```

Comment: Additionally, decent practice is to implement a cache factory and use an in between method like `User.valueOf()`.

Comment: You should *never* use the Player class as a field type. Store is it as the player's unique ID and set it using `player.getUniqueId();` in the constructor. You can then create a method such as `public void toPlayer()` which returns `Bukkit.getPlayer(player);`.

Comment: @Momo Not sure what you mean - how is having a `User` object with `Player` field worse than having a `Player` object (which would be the original situation)? Maybe I'm not understanding the context here, since I'm not familiar with Bukkit.

Comment: @Cinnam What I meant to say, is that storing `Player player` (the field) inside of another object (User) can result in memory leaks. It is more efficient and safe to use the UUID of the user to be stored in the User object.

Answer (score 0):

You could directly modify the source code for CraftPlayer in CraftBukkit and then use the CraftPlayer object.

Comment: this would be a really dumb and api breaking move!